# ReactJS local class variable geting cleared on ComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use a local variable for setting coloring the proper row in a table:

```
class CoaDataGrid extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.selected = "" <======= Local Class Variable
        this.state = {
            showinactive: false,
            search: "",
            sort: "account",
            sortdir: "asc",
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.selected = "TEST"
    }
    componentDidUpdate = () => {                
        console.log(this.selected) <======= Checking the Value Here
    }
    selectRecord = (e) => {
        this.selected = e.id <====== Setting the Value Here
        // Do Something Here to update the component
    }
    .....
```

I understand that this is just pseudoode; however if I set a local class variable and something causes the component to update, the class variable gets wiped out.  Is this by design?  Is there a workaround if it IS by design?

Comment: Are you re-rendering / updating your parent component?

Comment: Salmin - the parent component does update because I am sending it the parent ID of another grid component.  It doesn't re-render the current component - or it not supposed to.  The component is never unmounted and remounted

Comment: I could not reproduce your error. Would you mind forking the solution and see if you can give us some exampel code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-darkness-orqw8